# SSAS Development Using Top n In Queries

Tags: ssas

I'm fairly new to SSAS development and when the existing team was giving me a run through of the existing SSAS project they mentioned that every query has a `SELECT TOP *n*` in it that they then manually go into the XML file and comment out when they are ready to migrate to production (and make sure you pick an *n* that no one else is using).

This was done because it takes too long to import the data into Visual Studio without the TOP *n* in the queries.

**Is this really best practice, or is there a better way to set up the development environment so that you don't have to comment out code before a deployment?**

Comment: Ways to improve this: 1. Address this as a performance issue if possible (i.e. indexes etc.) 2. Reduce the total dataset in DEV; 3. Automate your deployment to remove the TOP N (not really recommended). I haven't used SSAS much but what do you mean by 'import the data into Visual Studio'. Do you mean there is some kind of design wizard you are going through, or does the cube take too long to build?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'll double check the steps tomorrow when I'm in the office.  I know we aren't using a design wizard at the moment.  I believe it is just when we open up a table in Visual Studio it pulls back all the data.  If the query is complex or returns a lot of data this can take a while, which is why the top n is used to limit the data returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about Analysis Services Tabular which does load the data at design time into memory in your "workspace database" which is usually a local Analysis Services Tabular instance.

You may consider creating a SQL view layer and building the Analysis Services model on top of the views. This recommendation is mentioned here with reasons:
http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2013/03/benefits-of-using-views-in-a-bi-solution/

But SELECT TOP X may not be enough. For example, if SELECT TOP 100 * FROM FactSales only returns fact rows for stores in the southwest but SELECT TOP 100 * FROM DimStore only returns stores in the northeast then it will be challenging to develop your model and calculations because everything will be rolling up to the blank store. So consider putting some more intelligent filter logic into the views.

Comment: yes it is Tabular.  Thanks for your reply.

So if I'm understanding you correctly, I can either put code in the tabular model that I comment out before going to production (which is what the team is doing now). Or I can create views that filter out data for the tabular model to read from but then I would need to modify the views when they get deployed to production (deploying the views would happen far less frequently I imagine than the tabular model).

Comment: Exactly. You understood me

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to change the MDX statements inside SSRS reports. If that is the case I would not suggest doing that. You need to see the performance of your reports on development environment as well. Of course, as suggested you can reduce the size of the data but that has big drawbacks since you cannot predict the real performance on Production anymore.

By the way, top n queries are generally very expensive since the results have to be calculated for the whole set and then get discarded. So advantage of having "top n" inside MDX to improve performance is pretty limited.